# Our database team wants to revoke the PUBLIC privilege to the packages UTL_FILE, UTL_HTTP, UTL_TCP, UTL_SMTP, DBMS_RANDOM

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am a Informatica developer and using source and target are Oracle database.
My database team asking that do you need EXECUTE permissions to the packages UTL_FILE, UTL_HTTP, UTL_TCP, UTL_SMTP, DBMS_RANDOM to my Database.

Can someone explain what is the impact of removing PUBLIC access to these packages and do I need these EXECUTE permissions to my database or not.

Answer (score 2):

What your database team wants to do is not unusual.  However, if they do this, they risk breaking things including your applications and tools (could be Oracle tools or 3rd party tools like SQL*Navigator).  They are making your company responsible to regression testing everything to ensure that it all still works (usually after they've replaced the PUBLIC grants with grants to individual accounts).

You can use the query below to see which PL/SQL code refers to this objects, to give you an idea of what you might need to regression test.

```
select  owner, 
        name object_name, 
        referenced_name references,
        referenced_type type
from    dba_dependencies
where   referenced_owner in ('SYS','PUBLIC')     and
        referenced_type in ('PACKAGE','SYNONYM')  and
        referenced_name IN ('UTL_FILE','UTL_HTTP','UTL_TCP','UTL_SMTP','DBMS_RANDOM') and
        owner <> 'SYS' and
        owner <> 'PUBLIC'
group by owner, name, referenced_name, referenced_type
order by owner, name, referenced_name, referenced_type;
```

This probably has a pretty good chance of being complete.  It will not show you usages from anonymous PL/SQL blocks submitted from externally (e.g, tools or web middle tiers or whatever), but those would be uncommon if not rare.  (Usually, anything embedded in such places would be DML, not anonymous PL/SQL blocks).

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is unusual. Our enterprise CERT requires this for all Oracle installations too.

Comment: @Michael-O The first line of my answer was that this is NOT unusual.  :)  Bad double-negative... sorry!

Comment: Ouch, just noticed that... ;-)